# Unable to generate console application using jpackage

Tags: java, windows, console-application, jpackage

When I run the following command under Windows 10 I end up with an EXE file:

`jpackage --win-console --module mymodule --module-path main.jar --module-path other-dependencies/ --app-version 1.0.0`

I am expecting to be able to run the EXE as a command-line application but instead running the EXE seems to install the application in the Start Menu and it seems to execute as a GUI application (exiting immediately, never outputting to stdout).

Am I supposed to be able to use `jpackage` to create a native binary that executes like a console application under Windows? Or did I misunderstand what `--win-console` is all about?

The only discussion I found is on [JDK-8253461](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8253461?focusedCommentId=14369983&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-14369983) but I don't understand what Andy Herrick meant. Why would a non-console application need access to stdin/stdout?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I supposed to be able to use jpackage to create a native binary that executes like a console application under Windows?

Yes, but not as a single self-contained executable.

By default `jpacakge` generates an installer (a .exe file on Windows). You can use `--type msi` to generate a .msi installer, or `--type app-image` to create an application image that can instead be zipped up and distributed. The application image contains the native binary.

For instance, if I use the following jpackage command:

```
jpackage --win-console --module mymodule --module-path mymodule.jar --type app-image --name myapp
```

`jpackage` creates a `myapp` folder, which contains a `myapp.exe` which can run as a console application:

```
> .\myapp\myapp.exe
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 0):

--win-console means that when you run your application it opens a terminal. You can use it to run the executable from the cmd and check the output for debugging. Once the application is fine, you can remove that option and build it again, so it no longer opens the terminal, but only opens your app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).